# Submitting multiple apk application to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have several apks for different screens and densities for my application. In manifest I set these limitations:

```
<compatible-screens>
   <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
   <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:largeScreens="true" adroid:normalScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

But in the developer console I cannot select devices supported for each apk, i.e., supported devices list:

```
Supported Devices [Learn More]
This application is only available to devices with these features, as defined in your application manifest.
Screen densities: NORMAL,HDPI LARGE,MDPI
Required device features
android.hardware.touchscreen
This application is available to over 0 devices.
```

So how do I customize apk distribution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if anyone will be confused as I was - just click "Activate" on the apk.